# Error while trying to get first element of sequence by index in a function call

Tags: clojure

I've encountered a problem while I was doing a task from [4clojure.com](http://www.4clojure.com/).
Here is the description of a task:

> Write a function which returns the last element in a sequence.

**I've solved it using the following code:**

```
#(first (reverse %))
```

When I wanted to change the `first` function with a number of an index.
like so:

```
#(0 (reverse %))
```

I've received an error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to
>   clojure.lang.IFn

**My question is:**
Why am I receiving this error?
I cannot get it, because for instance 
`([1 2 3 4] 0)` is perfectly valid and returns the first element of a sequence so why I cannot use index of an array in the function?

**EDIT1:**
Even the following code does not work and I suppose `APersistentVector` is first there.

```
#((reverse %) 0)
```

**EDIT2:**
I managed to make it work by converting the list which is returned from `reverse` function to vector. Thanks @Josh

```
(#((vec (reverse %)) 0)[1 2 3])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the code for [APersistentVector](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentVector.java#L18), you will see:

```
public abstract class APersistentVector extends AFn ...
```

`AFn` implements `IFn`, which extends java's `Callable` and `Runnable` interfaces, which means that a clojure persistent vector can be called as a function, with the argument being used as the index to retrieve. You can see this [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentVector.java#L291):

```
public Object invoke(Object arg1) {
    if(Util.isInteger(arg1))
        return nth(((Number) arg1).intValue());
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key must be integer");
}
```

The same is true for maps and sets; they can all be invoked as functions:

```
({:a 1 :b 2} :b)  ;; 2
(#{:a :b} :a)     ;; :a
([1 2 3 4] 0)     ;; 1
```

However, a `Long` (your number zero) does not implement `IFn`:

```
(ancestors (class 42))
=>
#{java.lang.Comparable
  java.lang.Number
  java.lang.Object
  java.io.Serializable}
```

Hence, it cannot be invoked as a function.

Comment: But wait `([1 2 3 4] 0)` works fine, so how it is possible that in this particular example it is invoked as a function?

Comment: @FieryCod Not sure I understand -- any clojure persistent vector that is the first element of a form (as in your example `([1 2 3 4] 0)` ) will be invoked as a function, always. What do you mean, "this particular example"?  `first` is a clojure core function, just to be clear.

Comment: By particular example I meant `([1 2 3 4] 0)`.
Ok if you say that any persistent vector that is the first element of a form will be invoked as a function please enlighten me why this
`#(((reverse %) 0))` throws an error?  If I understood you correctly it should work because `PersistentVector` is first.

Comment: You will notice that the error given when you try to apply that function to a sequence: `ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`.  `reverse` does not return a vector; it returns a `PersistentList`, and lists do not implement `IFn` (one reason being that lists are not associative, i.e., they cannot be accessed via an index like vectors) @FieryCod

Comment: Thank you, you've perfectly explained it. Have a nice day:)